# Select on tables from query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

In SQL Server 2005 I make a query that produces result set with following attributes :

```
TableName | ColumnName | SomeColumn
```

Can I somehow enhance this query so that for each record from that result set I would get `count of elements from that table` (or in general execute any query on the table and column specified on TableName, ColumnName? Can something like this be achieved:

```
SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Q.TableName) AS Cnt, (SELECT AVG(SomeColumn) FROM Q.TableName) AS AvgValue

FROM 
(`...OMITTED ORIGINAL QUERY...`) AS Q
```

?

The above query doesn't work. The error occurs: "Invalid object name 'Q.TableName'".

Is this possible in SQL Server 2005 with using only simple queries (without stored procedures)?

Sample data:

```
TableName | ColumName 

SomeTable1 | Column11
SomeTable1 | Column12
SomeTable2 | Column21
SomeTable2 | Column22
SomeTable3 | Column31
```

I would like for each row from that `sample data` have more attributes:

```
TableName | ColumName | CountInThatTable | AvgValueInThatColumnFromThatTable

SomeTable1 | Column11 | N1               | N11
SomeTable1 | Column12 | N1               | N12
SomeTable2 | Column21 | N2               | N21
SomeTable2 | Column22 | N2               | N22
SomeTable3 | Column31 | N3               | N31
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly then to achieve your result you need a dynamic query.
Below is a sample which you can utilize to achieve your result.

```
DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(100)
CREATE TABLE #tblRowCount (Id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
                           TableName VARCHAR(100), 
                           NoOfRows int)
DECLARE cur_trav  CURSOR FOR SELECT Name FROM sys.tables
OPEN cur_trav
FETCH NEXT FROM cur_Trav INTO @tableName
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(5000)

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS =0
BEGIN
SET @SQL =''
SET @SQL = ' INSERT INTO #tblRowCount (tableName, NoOfRows)  SELECT ''' + @TableName +''' as tableName , COUNT(1) as counter FROM ' + @TableName 
EXECUTE(@SQL)
--  --PRINT @sql
  FETCH NEXT FROM cur_Trav  
END 
CLOSE cur_Trav
DEALLOCATE cur_trav

SELECT Id,tableName, NoOfRows FROM #tblRowCount
DROP TABLE #tblRowCount
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a count of rows returns by the query, in a separate column on each row, then use window functions:

```
select . . .,
       count(*) over () as overall_cnt
from . . .;
```